# Faster text replacement

Tags: ruby

I wrote a method that corrects words like `Bahnstra\s39e` and replaces special characters like `\s39` with the associated unicodes `00DF` from the `@fields` array.

```
@fields = {"s39" => "00DF", ...}
```

The `@fields` array contains about 50 special characters and i noticed that because of my `correct(word)` method my code is very lame! What could i change to make it work faster? Thanks

```
def correct(word)
  @fields.each do |key, array|
    word.gsub! "\\" + key , [array.hex].pack("U")
  end
  return word.gsub(/\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/) {|m| [$1].pack("H*").unpack("n*").pack("U*")}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) method has a form with `Hash` as a replacement, so it would perfectly fit your needs.

```
@fields = { '\s39' => 'ß', … }
word.gsub(/\\s?d+/, @fields)
```

Update: made the `'s'` character optional in the regexp, by the specification of OP's in the comment

Comment: Sorry but one more question! What means your regex `/\\s\d+/` does it fullfil all of my characters in the array? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith It's a regular expression matching `'\s'` characters followed with at least one number. It matches `'\s39'`, `'\s101'`, `'\s1'` for example.

Comment: But there are also characters that dont begin with \s! But all begin with a `\\`

Comment: It was unclear from the orig. question but it's trivial to modify to your needs. Just exhaustively specify the pattern to match a replacement. What may follow the backslash ?